# Can uiautomator tests resume after a device restart?

Tags: android-uiautomator

I would like to write a test where the device is expected to restart.  Can uiautomator handle this kind of cases?

E.g.
1) Take a picture.
2) Reboot the device.
3) Check that the picture is still on the device.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible.. As `UIAutomator tests` run in the `shell` of your Android device..
You will need to take help of `adb` and `scripting language` like `perl` to handle such case..